# Use Coq to prove difference between relative numbers

Tags: coq

How do you prove: `forall m n : Z, m < n -> m -n < O` in Coq? Many Thanks!

Comment: I don't really like the edited title, but at least it doesn't look like random keyboard mashing now .. try for "something in English" for a title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just care about proving it, and not about the proof, just use omega:

```
Require Import Omega.

Goal forall m n : Z, (m < n)%Z -> (m - n < 0%Z)%Z.
intros. omega.
Qed.
```

---

If you have to prove this as part of exercises, or a homework, it is not too hard if you rely on some existing proofs.

For instance, you can combine these guys:

```
Zminus_diag_reverse
     : forall n : Z, 0%Z = (n - n)%Z

Zplus_lt_le_compat
     : forall n m p q : Z, (n < m)%Z -> (p <= q)%Z -> (n + p < m + q)%Z
```

There are definitely more than one way to do it, and it is not a very hard goal if you use some existing lemmas.